# Is it okay to mix underscores and dashes (hyphens) in CSS ID naming conventions?

Tags: css, html, naming-conventions

I have suggested to my team that we use dashes (hyphen) for our class names, but for ids, use an underscore to separate the element tag from the rest of the ID name, and that the ID name should be #element_class-name, so:
    `<div id="div_generic-name" class="generic-name">Stuff</div>`
Is there error to this method? What bad things can happen if we mix underscores and hyphens?

Comment: you should read some coding standards on css, like wordpress one, not something you should follow all the time but I really found that article useful when I started with css http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/css/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's no problem. Per the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), the top two rules of naming CSS classes are:

- All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e.,
  [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under
  the control of CSS. For example, the case-sensitivity of values of
  the HTML attributes "id" and "class", of font names, and of URIs lies
  outside the scope of this specification. Note in particular that
  element names are case-insensitive in HTML, but case-sensitive in
  XML.
- In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
  selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
  characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
  (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen
  followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters
  and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For
  instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26
  W\3F".

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with doing what you want to do. Anything between the quotes is not parsed by the browser and only treated as a character string and won't be interpreted.